How to read chainline specs for crankset and bottom bracket compatibility?
General question:
I've been trying to find a replacement crankset, but have been having trouble understanding other posts about compatibility with respect to chainline. It seems that people add the crankset chainline to the bottom bracket axle length and keep that consistent across FC/BB combinations. I have two issues: 1) since the crankset doesn't sit at the end of the axle, but rather set in some unspecified distance, isn't it feasible that the unspecified distance is variable between BB's? 2) I'm having quite a bit of trouble actually parsing the specs sheets for the chainline and axle length, which I've detailed some of below.
Specific specs sheet confusion
To be concrete, my crankset is an FC-C201. Depending on the "Front derailleur installation band diameter" (what does this mean?) the chainline seems to be either 47.5mm or 50mm:

Additionally, the spindle length (is this the same as the axle length?) is 116mm:

Now, I'm looking at the FC-TY501 as a replacement and the only specs I am able to find are on the product page. The chainline reads 47.5/47.5 + t/50:

What do the slashes and t mean? Additionally, there are two different O.L.D. measurements:

How are these different, and are they relevant in understanding what the resulting chainline would be? Finally, it gives some information on recommended bottom brackets:

What do the "normal" and "chain case" specifiers mean, what does the "Axle length of BB-UN/ES" mean, and what are "D-NL" and "D-EL"?
When I search the bottom brackets with the "normal" specifier, it appears that they could have a potentially variable axle length:



Is it that the letters "D-NL" and "D-EL" are specifying a particular bottom bracket length?
Thanks so much for any help, and many apologies for the length of this question!


It seems that people add the crankset chainline to the bottom bracket
axle length and keep that consistent across FC/BB combinations.

To clarify, most commonly manufacturers tend to provide data in this form: For square taper cranks and others where the BB spindle is a separate part, they tell you what the chainline of a given crank "is" and they tell you what BB spindle length it "takes." In the real world of fixing bikes, sometimes there is a need to make run cranks at other chainlines than that, say to make them work on old bikes or bike types not explicitly intended in the design. The basic logic to figure out what spindle to use instead is: "If spindle length X gives me chainline Y, and I need chainline Y-A, I need to run spindle length X-2A." For example, if 123mm is giving you 50 and you want 45, you run 113.

I have two issues: 1) since the crankset doesn't sit at the end of the axle,
but rather set in some unspecified distance, isn't it feasible that
the unspecified distance is variable between BB's?

That would be an issue if within a given taper standard (JIS and ISO), there was no standard for the starting thickness of the taper, or in other words if some tapers ran out longer than others. But this dimension is standardized, so there tends to negligible differences if any when using the above logic or switching between BB brands.

"Front derailleur installation band diameter" (what does this mean?)

The first table there is only talking about front derailleurs. The language you cite is Shimano obtusely reckoning with the fact that FD-C201-E would have problems with bottoming against the seattube  of a 34.9mm seattube bike while trying to shift into the inner ring if the crank was configured with 47.5mm chainline, so it needs to be at 50mm.


What do the slashes and t mean?

It's saying that the crank can be specced to run at 47.5, or at 47.5 with the addition of a chaincase whose support bracket is being held in place under the DS BB cup, or at 50mm. The "+t" is Shimano's insane way of talking about chaincases and showing product managers (and to a much lesser extent bike mechanics) which BB they'd need to order for a chaincase bike.


How are these different, and are they relevant in understanding what the resulting chainline would be?

This is Shimano providing the mostly useless information that this could be specced on a 142x12 or a 135mm rear end bike. It doesn't say anything useful for your purposes.

What do the "normal" and "chain case" specifiers mean, what does the "Axle length of BB-UN/ES" mean, and what are "D-NL" and "D-EL"?

D-NL and D-EL are JIS spindle codes. There are a lot of them.
As above, the "normal" and "chain case" specifiers are saying "this is what it takes to get to this target chainline with or without the presence of a chain case support bracket under the DS cup."
"Axle length" is the same thing as spindle length, "BB-UN/ES" is them saying "the relevant JIS BBs we make."
